# Typescript React how to skip useEffect iteration when modifying dependencies from certain function

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I have a `useEffect` hook that tracks the state variable `values`. I want to call the hook whenever `values` is changed. However, there is one case where I don't want to call the useEffect hook and that is when I am calling the function `handleReset()`. I attempt to set a flag `resetting` to true while in the function and then setting it to false after the function completes (the idea is to enter the `useEffect` hook but then skip it via `if(resetting.current)`... however, the **code never enters the if statement and does not skip if** `resetting.curent == true`.

How can I properly skip the call to useEffect if we are setting the dependency states via the handleReset() function?

```
export const Component: React.FC<Props> = ({}) => {
    const resetting = React.useRef(false);
    const [values, setValues] = React.useState(getDefaultValues());

    React.useEffect(() => {
        if (resetting.current) {
            // skip useEffect if we are in handleReset()
            return;
        }
        if (someCondition) {
            // do stuff
        }
    }, [values, resetting.current]);


    const handleReset = () => {
        resetting.current = true;
        setValues(getDefaultValues());
        resetting.current = false;
    };
    
    return ();
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the state is an async operation. When you call `handleReset`

```
const handleReset = () => {
    resetting.current = true;
    setValues(getDefaultValues());
    resetting.current = false; // <- this would happen before the useEffect is triggered
};
```

the `resetting.current` would be changed to `false` before updating the state, whoch would cause a re-render, and trigger the `useEffect`.

Instead, change `resetting.current` to `false` in the `useEffect` if `resetting.current` is `true`:

```
export const Component: React.FC < Props > = ({}) => {
  const resetting = React.useRef(false);
  const [values, setValues] = React.useState(getDefaultValues());

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (resetting.current) {
      // skip useEffect if we are in handleReset()
      resetting.current = false; // change resetting to false
      return;
    }
    if (someCondition) {
      // do stuff
    }
  }, [values]); // you don't need resetting.current as a dependency. It's a ref, and the useEffect would be triggered by the values change


  const handleReset = () => {
    resetting.current = true;
    setValues(getDefaultValues());
  };

  return ();
};
```